# I was a bad boy: Firefox addon to edit body of post request (which I am doing manually atm)

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to intercept POST request, change a parameter and let it continue in Mozilla addon.

Background:
I am part of the comment section of example.org. That site had an option in profile to allow to show 10, 25, 50, 100 and 500 comments per page. A week ago, in order to save bandwidth, they removed that option and locked the users to 50 comments per page or less.

I was a naughty boy and researched a bit.

There is https://example.org/api.html?GET_COMMENTS post method.

As part of a JSON object in the body  of request, it takes preferred_count parameter. The object looks something like this

> { userid: 1234567,
>
> postId: 56789,
>
> preferred_count: 50,
>
> location_parameters:[] etc}

My research lead me to a discovery that if I change preferred_count to 500 in the request body in Firefox developer tools then resend the request I will get full 500 comments on that post as a response! Neat. But it sucks to be doing it constantly. So I tried to develop a firefox addon to do it for me.

My manifest.json looks like this:

> {
>
> ```
> "description": "Makes example comments.cool.",
> "manifest_version": 2,
> "name": "examplecomments",
> "version": "1.0",
> "permissions": [
>     "webRequest",
>     "webRequestBlocking",
>     "storage",
>     "https://example.com/*",
>     "https://example.org/api.html?GET_COMMENTS"
>
> ],
> "icons": {
>     "48": "border.png",
>     "96": "border.png"
> },
> "applications": {
>     "gecko": {
>         "id": "borderify@example.com"
>     }
> },
>
>  "background": {
>      "scripts": [ "badComments.js" ]
>  } }
> ```

My badComments.js looks like this:

```js
var lookUrl = "https://example.com/api.phtml?GET_COMMENTS";

function moreComments(requestResp) {
    var dec = new TextDecoder();
    var enc = new TextEncoder();

    if (requestResp.url.toLowerCase() == lookUrl.toLowerCase()) {


        console.log(requestResp);

        var rawBytes = requestResp.requestBody.raw[0].bytes;
        var decoded = dec.decode(rawBytes)
        console.log(decoded);
        var requestedObject = JSON.parse(decoded);
        var numberOnPage = requestedObject.body[1].server_get_comments.preferred_count;
        console.log(numberOnPage);
        numberOnPage = 500;
        console.log(numberOnPage);
        requestedObject.body[1].server_get_comments.preferred_count = numberOnPage;
        console.log( requestedObject.body[1].server_get_comments.preferred_count);
       
        var requestedObjString = JSON.stringify(requestedObject);
        console.log(requestedObjString);
        var encodedObject = enc.encode(requestedObjString);
        console.log(encodedObject);
        requestResp.requestBody.raw[0].bytes = encodedObject.buffer;

        console.log(requestResp);



    }

   return {requestBody:requestResp.requestBody}; 
  //  return {requestBody:requestResp};

}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  moreComments,
   { urls: [lookUrl] }, 
  ["blocking", "requestBody"]
);
```

Console shows that preferred_count gets replaced with the correct number. But after scanning it in firefox console doesn't show it, it remains the old one! And I never get my 500 comments. What am I doing wrong? How can I change request, or, failing that, stop the existing one, copy all the needed data for request and send my own?

thank you.